# Is it possible to install different versions of Java for browsers for seperate users in Windows

Tags: windows, java, java-applet

I have a peculiar situation.
My dad uses the PC using a separate account (low privileges). He needs to be on the current version of Java 1.7.45 to run an applet on a specific non-public site. It has to run within IE.
Note: He cannot stop using the site, it is for work. They are doing some really insecure things with Java, which I think newer versions will block (they are already on the edge of 'it works'.)

I want to update the Java for my user account to the latest fixes as they are released.

Is it possible to get his IE to use the older Java and my account to move forward?

Virtualization is not an option, windows licenses are too expensive.

Currently using:
Windows 8.0, IE 10, Java 1.7.45.

Comment: looking for an answer to this also

Comment: I haven't found the answer yet. Although, I think the latest JRE update allows usage of some sort of whitelist for websites. I plan to try using it.

Comment: I didnt find a concrete answers so I signed my jars using https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Signing_jar_files_with_jarsigner and now they work with the latest java version